# The curious case of "if" in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

While working on something, I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
if(true) {
    String message = "Assignment possible";
}

if(true)
    String message = "Time to leave earth";  // error!
```

Why is there a compilation error in the second case when it is possible to write 'if' conditions in java without the braces?

The error message doesn't seem to give a proper info:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
String cannot be resolved to a variable
message cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Can someone explain this?

Comment: Is this in the same file? I think conditional definition doesn't work, and the previous statement already defined a String called "message". The second statement tries to redefine it, and this gives this strange error message.

Comment: Where would you use that string `message` ? if there is no block you can't use it after .. It makes no sense to write this

Comment: To be obtuse, it is not allowed because the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) doesn't allow it; see the linked duplicate for more in depth explanations.

Answer (score 14):

You can't declare a variable inside an if statement unless you surround the declaration with curly braces, since the declaration must have a scope.

This would work, since the variable is declared outside the if statement :

```
String message;
if(true)
    message = "Assignment possible";
System.out.println(message)
```

This doesn't pass compilation, since the variable would be declared in the same scope as the surrounding code, but it would only be declared if the condition is true, so `System.out.println(message)` will not have a `message` variable to print in all cases :

```
if(some condition)
    String message = "Time to leave earth";
System.out.println(message);
```

The fact that your condition is always true doesn't make a difference, since the compiler must support all outcomes of any if condition.

Now, when you surround the declaration with curly braces, you restrict your declared variable to a new scope :

```
if(some condition) {
    String message = "Time to leave earth";
    System.out.println(message); // this will pass compilation since message
                                 // is guaranteed to be found in this scope
}
System.out.println(message); // this won't pass compilation, since message is not 
                             // found in this scope
```

Answer (score 0):

The controlled-statement of an `if` statement is either a single statement or a block. A single statement cannot be a declaration-statement.